# How does react redux's actions have access to dispatch and getState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, redux, react-redux

In the reddit example of the [react redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html), how does the actions.js have access to the dispatch and getState functions even though they were never imported? I thought you have to import each method in each file that you use.

Comment: It is returning a function which has 2 arguments `dispatch` and `getState`. But this function is consumed by the `react-redux` connect function. Even if the arguments are named to some other name other than `dispatch` or `getState` it will just work without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code uses [thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js#L4), read the [async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) section to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have access to the functions from the external libraries.

In `fetchPostsIfNeeded`, those are locally-defined function parameters. You could rename them anything you wanted as long as you renamed the rest of the code that calls the parameters. For example

```
export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(subreddit) {
  return (fireAction, findState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(findState(), subreddit)) {
      return fireAction(fetchPosts(subreddit))
    }
  }
}
```

is equally as valid as

```
export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(subreddit) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
      return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
    }
  }
}
```

however, the naming is user-friendly for the docs, because fetchPostsIfNeeded expects to be able to dispatch the inner action creator `fetchPosts()` through the redux pipeline.

In this case, the real store's dispatch function is most likely being dependency injected through props, and you can think of passing it to an anonymous function, as a parameter, a continuation of that pattern inside the action creator itself.

There are a bunch of solid videos on good patterns for passing the store through an app on Dan Abramov's [free courses on egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-explicitly-via-props?course=getting-started-with-redux).